# maven project intellij java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup

Tags: java, rest, maven, jax-rs

I have a java maven project and I use jax-rs for http GET,POST requests. Inside that rest controller class I'm calling getHTML content (using jsoup) in another class. Then this `NoClassDefFroundErrorr` comes. I have already added the maven dependency and added the jar as well. Any reasons for this error?

**This is my jsoup code:**

```
public static ArrayList<StringBuilder> getHTMLContent(ArrayList newsUrl) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ArrayList<StringBuilder> descriptionList = new ArrayList();
    Document document;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        System.out.println(newsUrl.get(i));
        try {
            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect((String) newsUrl.get(i))
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .timeout(12000)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .execute();


            document = response.parse();
            Elements paragraphs = document.body().select("p");
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            for (Element element : paragraphs) {
                //removing advertisement tag
                if (!element.text().equals("Advertisement") &&
                        !element.text().contains("|") &&
                        !element.text().contains(":") &&
                        !(element.text().trim().split(" ").length == 1) &&
                        !(element.text().trim().contains("Home Page"))) {
                    content.append(element.text());
                    content.append("\n");
                }
            }
            descriptionList.add(content);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

    return descriptionList;

}
```

I call the method like this inside the rest controller

```
ArrayList<StringBuilder> descriptions = api_client.getHTMLContent(urls);
```

Comment: Show us the pom pls. its a dependency issue, we should check that first

Comment: Are you running this from a jar or ide?

Comment: You get *what* `NCDF` error?! Can't read your mind or screen.

Comment: @vikingsteve please find my pom here http://textuploader.com/dufhb

Comment: @DaveNewton java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
 at SummarizerAlgorithm.Api_Client.getHTMLContent(Api_Client.java:34)

Comment: @Matt from ide - intellij

Comment: any suggestions? I think the libraries used by the classes outside the rest controller class is not identified by the rest class inside the @GET method. Because I cannot make any API call or make database connection as well

Comment: Add the exception to the question. In any case, it can come from a variety of reasons as detailed in the dupe. You'll need to diagnose and debug.